# Excel cell formula is updating with sheet name. Exporting from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, export, export-to-excel

```
=CONCATENATE( "Level3!$B",  MATCH($B6,Level31!$A:$A,0),":$B", COUNTIF(Level31!$A:$A,$B6) + MATCH($B6,Level31!$A:$A,0)-1)
```

I have this formula in excel cell. Which I am copy pasting in all the rows below through C# code. It is fine till here.

The problem is that in this formula `Level3` was a sheet name which is renamed to `Level31`. This change is reflecting in formula automatically in three places and not on first place..Why
After manual formula update in cell it works fine.

Second problem is in next cell
where another formula is implemented. When I am opening sheet it shows `#N/A`
but when I click in the cell and hit enter key. It starts working..

Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to first place as `=CONCATENATE( "Level3!$B",` , that value is stored as string and will not automatically adjust from 3 to 31. Try this formula `=CONCATENATE(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"!$B", MATCH($B6,Level31!$A:$A,0),":$B", COUNTIF(Level31!$A:$A,$B6) + MATCH($B6,Level31!$A:$A,0)-1)`
formula `MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)` makes your first place also dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used your provided formula but I could not understand it. So I went with another way. I made formula in back end code as required.